# Regex for an alphanumeric string of specific length with at least one letter and at least one digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match alphanumeric string of specific length with at least one letter and at least one digit.

For example, `adfyg43`2 should contain alphabetic and digit and the length should start from 8.

I used this expression but it won't work:

```
^([A-Za-z]{1,}\d{1,}){8,}$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current pattern repeats a group 8 or more times. That group by itself matches 1 or more chars a-z followed by 1 or more digits.

That means that the minimum string length to match is 16 chars in pairs of at least 2. So for example a string like `a1aa1a1a1a1a1a1a1` would match.

---

You could write the pattern using 2 lookahead assertions to assert a length of at least 8 and assert at least a char a-z.

Then match at least a digit. Using a case insensitive match:

```
^(?=[a-z\d]{8,}$)(?=\d*[a-z])[a-z]*\d[a-z\d]*$
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[a-z\d]{8,}$)` Positive lookahead, assert 8 or more chars a-z or digits till end of string
- `(?=\d*[a-z])` Positive lookahead to assert at least a char a-z
- `[a-z]*` Match optional chars a-z
- `\d` Match at least a single digit
- `[a-z\d]*` Match optional chars a-z or digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v1SjpD/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?=[a-z\d]{8,}$)(?=\d*[a-z])[a-z]*\d[a-z\d]*$/i;
[
  "AdfhGg432",
  "Abc1aaa"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`Match "${s}": ${regex.test(s)}`)
)
```

Comment: It works. good. But I cant understand it . could you please describe it more or write it in  a simple way

Comment: @albert I have added a breakdown of the pattern.

Comment: I am constantly amazed by your ability to decipher questions that unfathomable by others. I've tried to figure out your method, ruling out every possibility but one. Guided by Sherlock Holmes' famous  quote, "When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth",  I've concluded you must have found a way to establish a mind meld with askers, but that means you must be  at least part-Vulcan.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Google tells me that Vulcan is the Roman god of fire :-) Don't tell anybody, but in reality I am just a mere mortal with a particular interest in regex. Unfortunately I don't have the gift of foresight, but based on the given pattern by the OP I tried to deduce the desired mechanism for the match.

Comment: Let me guess: yes, one can simplify `(?=[a-z\d]{8,}$)` to `(?=[a-z\d]{8})` but the former is faster.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You could also use the simplified pattern of course, but I used the assertion till the end of the string because when you have this string `adfafds233@` the assertion without the anchor will be true but the pattern will fail later on while matching.